# How do I create a GitLab webhook?

Tags: git, gitlab, webhooks

I've read that GitLab is capable of sending messages to other servers via "web hooks" but I can't find *where* one would create one.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

All the answers I've found in official documentation and on Stack Overflow for finding **web hooks** are incorrect. The `admin area > hooks` page does NOT contain **web** hooks. It contains **system** hooks, which fire when you create/delete projects and users and things like that. This is not what you want.

To find your web hooks, go to the `specific project > settings > web hooks (on sidebar in GitLab 6.1.0)` page. These will fire on post-receive for the project in question. You can use a service like [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/) to see what the payload looks like and to ensure you're firing these off correctly for debugging purposes.

Comment: A more accurate answer than mine. +1. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jamey. There is official documentation on GitLab web and server hooks in the application itself: http://demo.gitlab.com/help/web_hooks and http://demo.gitlab.com/help/system_hooks. The login credentials for the demo server are listed on http://demo.gitlab.com/.

Comment: That's great! It still doesn't tell you *where* to find the web hooks, though. That's the issue that @leech and I were experiencing a while back.

Comment: The system hooks are still web hooks, they're just web hooks for system events instead of repository events.

Comment: is this only possible through the site or can webhooks be created with the api?

Comment: Webhooks are activated and "configured" through the website. But backend implementation documentation is [GItlab Webhooks doc](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md)

Comment: There is also a nice wiki here: [Gitlab Webhooks wiki](https://kanboard.net/plugin/gitlab-webhook)

Comment: This answer is obsolete, please refer to @derwiwie 's answer

Answer (score 30):

With version 8.16.1, I found the web hooks under

```
specific project > settings > integrations
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**For group level hooks:**

visit: `https://gitlab.com/groups/<yourgroup>/hooks`

For group project level hooks:

visit: `https://gitlab.com/yourgroup/yourproject/hooks`

Answer (score 4):

You can see an example of GitLab system hook, with  a [web_hook.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/models/web_hook.rb) creation in this [GitHub project](https://github.com/shawn-sterling/gitlab-webhook-receiver).

> In gitlab, as admin, go to "`Hooks`" tab, create hook as: http://your.ip.goes.here:8000
>
> or change the port on line 175 of the script.

For web hooks, see [Jamey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941605/jamey)'s [more accurate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901502/6309).

You can inspect the result of a webhook with a service like [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/).
Another example of webhook interpretation: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17129781/6309).

Be aware though that a few issues remain with gitlab webhook:

- [it is not always firing](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gitlabhq/s-aV8ov_rh8)
- [There's no URL nor namespace key present on system's webhook](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3836)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [GitLabForm](https://github.com/egnyte/gitlabform) - configuration as code tool for GitLab - to configure webhooks with code like this:

```yaml
project_settings:
  my_group/my_project:
    hooks:
      hooks:
      'http://127.0.0.1:5000/hooks/my-hook-endpoint':
        push_events: false # this is set to true by GitLab API by default
        merge_requests_events: true
        token: some_secret_auth_token
```

**Disclosure:** I wrote this tool and my company open-sourced it.