# Which is the best git hosting sw? - Gitolite vs. Gitlab vs. Gitorius

Tags: git, hosting, gitolite, gitlab, gitorious

I am looking for a git hosting environment for several users. Therefore i've searched for comparisons between **Gitolite**, **Gitlab** and **Gitorius**. But i get nothing what could be useful.

Is there anybody, who has experiences with different hosting tools and could provide an advice?

Comment: There's also [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/) which is a turn-key Git hosting solution written in Java (using JGit).

Comment: This might help you: [Gitorious vs Gitlab vs GitHub: Three Git Systems](http://www.boxuk.com/blog/a-tale-of-three-git-systems/). Has all the research behind the companies transition from Subversion towards Git with an analysis of the Git systems.

Comment: If anyone is coming here and just wants a decision made for them, go with ***Gitlab***. You can't really go wrong with it. Also look up Bitnami's gitlab stack if installing it sounds too hard.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

- [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) is **not** a git hosting environment: it is an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html), which grants or denies access to a git repo.
  It is the https or ssh layer which allows the authentication of a user, and the git repo hosting itself.
  See "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)"
- [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/) and [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) both provide git hosting, with (to my opinion) an easier installation process and more features for GitLab.

When comparing [GitLab features](http://www.gitlab.com/features/) and [Gitorious features](http://gitorious.org/about), the issue tracker is more complete, the fork and authorization levels are present, GitLab has [teams *and groups*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15894795/6309), [webhooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17162353/6309), and API.
The development is more active (one release every month) on GitLab.

Update: [GitLab has acquired Gitorious](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/03/03/gitlab-acquires-gitorious/)

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. But what are the main features which gitlab does provide and gitorius not?

Comment: @user2451418 I have added multiple links and edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Don't forget about gitblit - http://gitblit.com/

Comment: GitLab, hands down!  It's easy to install and maintain, and an active developer community means that it is constantly evolving.  I have launched it at my company and everyone loves it.

Answer (score 4):

You can give Gitorious and Gitlab a try at Bitnami (http://bitnami.com/stack/gitorious and http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab)  There you can download installers, virtual machines and launch cloud servers for Amazon and Azure. All of these options are free. You can launch a 1-hour demo server as well (if you just want to get a quick feeling for the app). Disclaimer: I am one of the Bitnami developers, but as stated above, the packages are completely free to use.