# How can I create a new GitLab Project Service?

Tags: tfs, gitlab, tfsbuild

I am currently evaluating GitLab for the development process in a new team. For reasons that are beyond my control I need to integrate with TFS build (so that a merge request kicks off a new build and the build reports status to the merge request, etc). It seems, from what I have learned so far, that the only way to achieve this seamlessly would be with a new Project Service.

Is this true and if so how would I go about creating one?

I have searched through the relevant docs and forums and I can't find much information of use so I suspect that Project Services are less of an arbitrary, open plug-in style model but rather more a core part of the product.  I am hoping to be proved wrong...

Answer (score 0):

If the integrate of GitLab and TFS build means you want through GitLab to queue the  TFS build automatically.

You may have to create your own service to receive the [webhooks](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md) form Gitlab([How do I create a GitLab webhook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157969/how-do-i-create-a-gitlab-webhook)). And then trigger TFS build.

Comment: You can also try to use  [*Cloudpipes*](https://www.cloudpipes.com/integrations/gitlab/team-foundation-server)   Integrate GitLab with Team Foundation Server. However, which is not free.

Comment: @Parrick-MSFT I can't use CloudPipes because this is all on-premise. I wanted to avoid using an intermediary service altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at:

(paths taken from docker container)
`/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/…`

- [`…/app/models/project_services/`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/app/models/project_services/)

  - have a look at the template: [`app/models/project_services/ci_service.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/app/models/project_services/ci_service.rb)
- [`…/app/models/project.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/app/models/project.rb)
- [`…/app/models/service.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/app/models/service.rb)
- [`…/lib/api/v3/services.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/api/v3/services.rb)
- [`…/lib/api/services.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/api/services.rb)

where the first three are the most relevant, the api to complete the REST services.

But no, I wasn't able to find any documentation either...